# Why can't I add LDBL_EPSILON to 1

Tags: c++, c++builder

This is my code. Why doesn't my first line of code work properly?

```
long double X;
X = 1.0 + 4.0*LDBL_EPSILON;                // The result is always 1.0
X = (long double)1.0 + 4.0*LDBL_EPSILON;   // Gives the correct result sometimes.

X = LDBL_EPSILON;
X += 1.0;          // These 2 lines seem to always give the correct result.
```

The erratic behavior noted above changes between builds, without any changes to this particular code. I am using C++ Builder XE3. Do I need to set a compiler switch to use long doubles properly, or is this a compiler bug, or what?

Edit: I tried using this line of code, and it appears to always work.

```
X = fabsl(1.0) + 4.0*LDBL_EPSILON;
```

Edit2 per Bob__'s question

```
long double X;
const long double epsilon = 1.084202172485504434E-19;
X = 1.0 + 14.0*epsilon;   // This result is correct
```

But if I replace epsilon with LDBL_EPSILON in the line of code, I can easily reproduce the problem.

Edit3: With Bob__'s help, I found that my definition of LDBL_EPSILON did not have the 'L' suffix. I don't know why it worked sometimes, and not others, but nevertheless, adding the suffix appears to have fixed my problem.

Thank you Bob!

Comment: `1.0` and `4.0` are both `double` and not `long double`. Might affect the result.

Comment: I tried casting the 4.0 as a long double, it doesn't help.

Comment: visual studio 2015 gives correct results. Also: LDBL_EPSILON is the same as DBL_EPSILON in VS.

Comment: In Builder, LDBL_EPSILON = 1.084202172485504434E-19 while DBL_EPSILON =2.2204460492503131E-16

Comment: If the result changes between builds the problem is most likely somewhere else. This code does not compile. Post a minimal example that compiles, runs, and shows the problem.

Comment: Does your compiler implement [std::nextafter](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/nextafter) ? Is the result of that consistent over multiple compilations?

Comment: @Pete Becker  Why doesn't this code compile? I am showing the entire function here, and in my compiler, the problem shows up, but the problem can change between builds. For example, if I change the 4 to a 16 and recompile.

Comment: @Bob__ My compiler doesn't support nextafter.

Comment: To be clear, if you explicitly set `const long double epsilon = 1.0842E-19L;` the results aren't incosistent between different builds, right?

Comment: @Bob__ See my second edit. Using the code I showed seems to fix the problem. I tried recompiling about 20 times and it always worked. The only thing I changed between compiles is the factor on epsilon.

Comment: Well, it seems that sometimes your compiler define the LDBL_EPSILON with the same size of a double, and sometimes not ( try to print out its `sizeof` and its value along various builds )... Which is a bit too weird, there must be a problem somewhere else.

Comment: To be even more clear, when you say "if I change the 4 to a 16 and recompile" you mean that ALL the times the parameter is 4.0 the X stay equal to 1.0 and ALL the times you change the parameter to 16.0 the X change? Because if it's so, as axalis said in his answer, your library simply define  LDBL_EPSILON as a double.

Comment: No, if I change the 4 to a 16 was just an example. However, when I checked the sizeof( LDBL_EPSILON) it returns a value of 8, not 10 as I would have expected. I am trying to see if I can ever get it to return 10.

Comment: @Bob__ See my last edit. Thanks for your help. If you want to give an answer, I'll be happy to check it as such.

Answer (score 2):

If you want long double in the calculation, you should use the long double suffix.

I.e. it should be:

```
X = 1.0L + 4.0L * LDBL_EPSILON;
```

Apparently LDBL_EPSILON is so small that when added to 1.0 double, it is cut off. On some compilers, the LDBL_EPSILON might be defined without a suffix, so it doesn't force the calculation to be done in long double.

Comment: I have tried this as well, but it doesn't help. The most troubling aspect of this problem is that it isn't consistent between builds.